# <canvas /> and print screen/screenshot

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, screenshot

Is there any way to `print screen` and get the clipboard data into an [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) element?

In other words, is there a way to read `print screened` clipboard data (pixels, probably) with javascript?

Or once again this is the case where [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) cannot get such data?

If any of the questions has the answer value of `yes`, I'd like to know a bit more details.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a way, it's Chrome only, but it works flawlessly.

http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/

I hope it's only a matter of time until other browsers implement similar features, but yeah, there is a way. Plus, this could be tweaked to do almost anything.

Answer (score 3):

You want to capture the screen and display it in canvas. Please see following link

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not, for security reasons.

The only thing that comes close is Mozilla's `drawWindow` command which only works locally.

Comment: I suspect, you might also be able to get the clipboard via Flash and perhaps from there into a canvas. At that point, though, you are dealing with ActionScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure about flash but it is true that you can do similar with java applets.